# Creation of file using input stream causes access denied issue

Tags: wcf, using, fileinputstream

I have created a WCF method which will  create a file based on the input stream passed.First time the method is invoked,it creates the file with out any problem.next time invocation causes issue access denied to the path...any help to sort out the issue.

the wcf  function is as follows

```
  public void UploadFile1(RemoteFileInfo1 request)
        {
            FileStream targetStream = null;
            Stream sourceStream = request.FileByteStream;

            request.FilePath = "\\" + request.FilePath;


            if (!Directory.Exists(request.FilePath))
            {

                Directory.CreateDirectory(request.FilePath);

            }
            string filePath = Path.Combine(request.FilePath, request.FileName);

            using (targetStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                //read from the input stream in 6K chunks
                //and save to output stream
                const int bufferLen = 65000;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
                int count = 0;
                while ((count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
                {
                    targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                targetStream.Close();
                sourceStream.Close();
            }        

        }
```

the request.filepath is a shared drive location

Comment: See http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities